# How do I add two applications/pages onto my Django-site?

Tags: django, web, python-3.5

I have been trying twice now to add a second application onto my Django-site, whereas it results in some kind of errors.

I have followed instructions from youtube which has been of great help but now I am stuck at adding a second page. My first one is working just fine.

This is my main url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^table/', include('table.urls')),

url(r'^', include('login.urls')),

]
```

This is my main settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'login',

'table',

....
TEMPLATES = [

{
    'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.templates.context_processors.debug',
            'django.templates.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

This is my working page url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views


urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

This is my working page view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):

return render(request,'login/login.html', {'content': ['username', 

'password']} )
```

This is my non-working page url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views



urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),

]
```

This is my non-working page view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):



return render(request,'table/table.html')
```

Thus far I have thought of the index(request) being an issue since they are both having the name "view" and same function name...?

And I have no idea where to look on the "error-page" nor what to show you guys, I'm sorry. And I appreciate any help. Thank you.

"During handling of the above exception ('django'), another exception occurred:
C:\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
response = get_response(request) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exc 
ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'django.templates'",)
get_response
>>>
>
request 
"

**EDIT:** I have named all my template-folders templates, always. Though I mistakenly named it without an s while creating it inside the second application but it is changed by refactoring.

I think this is my error now:

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'django.templates'

Comment: I am not sure, but given the error **No module named 'django.templates'** I think you may have written a mistake in an import statement somewhere in that app or a typo in your settings file. There is a module django.template, but no django.templates.

Comment: Yeah I believe this is my error message if I understood it all correctly:

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'django.templates'

Comment: Have you found it? If not, check your TEMPLATES setting (there are some **django.template.x** modules set) or possibly your views.py or forms.py file import statements: **from django.templates import x**. You most likely need to change _django.templates_ to _django.template_ somewhere.

Comment: Omg it helped to remove the "s"'s from the settings-file! I just feel WOW. :O

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: So now my problem is solved, how do I mark it as solved? :o /The Noob. :D

Comment: I will create an answer which you can then accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is stating you are referring to django.templates somewhere. This module does not exist in django, but django.template does. You can find several django.template.x statements in your settings.py file.

Replace django.templates.x with django.template.x and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py, specify the app_name like this:

```
# ...imports...

app_name = 'tables'
urlpatterns = [
#...
]
```

The name of the url can then be accessed by your template by tables:index

Comment: Thanks, I added it though it did not help this particular issue... It seems that it might have something to do with templates. It is so hard to read the errors and I appreciate your kindness very much. :)